# How do toggle elements when option is selected?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to toggle checkboxes based on the option chosen from the `select`.
Here is my selector inside `insertUser` template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="userType">User Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="userType">
        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="user">Normal User</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And I have check box as follow:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="rm">Remove Users</label>
</div>
```

I want to view the checkbox when Admin is selected from the selector and hide it when Normal User is selected, How should I go about doing it?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post your JS.

Comment: @KoshVery I didn't forget, I just don't know how to go about it. I only know how to retrieve the value once a button is selected through events. But I don't know how to make real time changes. For buttons, we use 'click #buttonID' but for selector, what should I use?

Comment: You can use `change` for `select` element.

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery if you are using BlazeJS (the default templating lib in meteor). When possible, always use Blaze instead of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meteor way:

1. Wrap the checkbox inside an if block
2. Set a session var based on the dropdown.
3. If the user is admin, show the checkbox.

---

**template:**

```
    <template name="wow">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userType">User Type:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="userType">
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="user">Normal User</option>
        </select>

<!-- here is the if block -->

{{#if isAdmin}}           
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="rm">Remove Users</label>
</div>
{{/if}}

<!-- if block ends -->

    </div>
    </template>
```

**helper:**

```
Template.wow.helpers({
    // returns only when isAdmin is true.
    isAdmin: function(){
        return Session.get("isAdmin");
    }
});


Template.wow.events({
    // check for the change in value of the dropdown. If admin is chosen, set the isAdmin session variable.

    'change #userType'(event){
        if(event.target.value == 'Admin'){
            Session.set('isAdmin', true);
        }
    }
});

//For the sense of completeness, unset the used session variable when the template gets destroyed.

Template.wow.onDestroyed(function(){
   Session.set("isAdmin", undefined);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hide()` and `show()` method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#userType').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'admin') {
            $('.checkbox').show();
        } else {
            $('.checkbox').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/dgqatjj1/1/)